# Soundcloud SC.stream() : waveforms and autoplay

Tags: javascript, syntax, soundcloud, waveform

I'm using soundcloud API for an app. The first thing my code does is to get my favorite tracks on soundcloud. Each track is displayed as a li element using Jquery. When I click one of those list elements, soundcloud loads the associated track and displays its waveform.

```
SC.get(track_url, function(track){
   var waveform = new Waveform({
      container: document.getElementById("waveform"),
      innerColor: "#333"
   });
   waveform.dataFromSoundCloudTrack(track);
   var streamOptions = waveform.optionsForSyncedStream();
   SC.stream(track.uri, streamOptions, function(stream){
       window.exampleStream = stream;
   }); // SC.stream
}); //SC.get()
```

Here `track_url` is the uri of the track I clicked on (http://api.soundcloud.com/...), and `#waveform` is the div where the waveform is going to be displayed.

Everything works fine. When i click on one of my favorite tracks, the player loads the song and the waveform, but **the song is not playing automatically**..

How can I combine the SoundManager2 `autoPlay` parameter and Waveform.js `waveform.optionsForSyncedStream();` in a single SC.stream() method ? I think it's a syntax problem but I can't solve it.

```
SC.stream(track.uri, {autoplay:true}, streamOptions, function(stream){
       window.exampleStream = stream;
   }); // SC.stream
```

With this code the song plays automatically when clicked, but the synced stream is not working anymore because SC.stream's third parameter is supposed to be a function... (Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function).

Please help !! :)

Comment: I have created a waveform with souncloud and waveform.js but it is static and doesn't animate when the sound plays. I have followed every step of the waveform.js documentation but still no luck. I am using javascript SDK version 3.0. I think waveform.js has not been updated to work with this version 3.0.Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found that installing SoundManager2 on your website provides you more control over sounds in general. To solve my problem I just had to set the default `autoPlay` option of Soundmanager to `true`.

Added the Soundmanager SDK to my html header. Created a new script.

```
soundManager.setup({
    onready: function() {
        soundManager.defaultOptions = {
           autoPlay: true
        }
    }
});
```

Then i went

```
SC.stream(track.uri, streamOptions, function(stream){
   window.exampleStream = stream;
}); // SC.stream
```

Comment: Is it possible to autoPlay on mobile devices with this approach? Couldn't make it run, cause i don't know what you are doing with `window.exampleStream`

Comment: How do you Stop the Track from playing?

Answer (score 0):

It should work without the SoundManager. SoundCloud will initiate this library regardless - check the [API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#streaming). Looks like you had one too many parms in .stream()

```
SC.stream(track.uri , { autoPlay: true });
```